# C# Resize Image with No Interpolation

Tags: c#, graphics, paint, interpolation, antialiasing

I know this question has been asked frequently, but none of the typical answers have given me the result I need.  I am attempting to zoom a grayscale bitmap much like Paint.exe.  I want no interpolation so the original, individual pixels can be observed.  I have tried the oft-suggested NearestNeighbor approach which gets close, but not exactly what I want.

This is what I want:

[image: Here is what I need]

This is what I get:

[image: Here is what I get with my application]

This is the code I am using to zoom and redraw the image.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;
    e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;            
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;

    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    m.Scale(mScale, mScale, MatrixOrder.Append);
    e.Graphics.Transform = m;

    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(this.AutoScrollPosition.X / mScale,this.AutoScrollPosition.Y / mScale);

    if (mImage != null) 
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(mImage, 0, 0);

    base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

The code does have an affect on the image as the zoom works and changing the InterpolationMode does change the image.  However, no combination of settings gets the result I need.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue.  What does the original image look like?  What is the value of mScale?

Comment: mScale is variable, but in the example I posted it was set to 5.0. Here's the image: http://i.imgur.com/pwdcfH6.png?1

Comment: Still can't reproduce your issue with the code provided.  I get the first image, not the second.

Comment: This might not help at all -- a nearest neighbor interpolation should give you exactly that result you're after, but it might help to simplify what you are doing a bit and use this overload of DrawImage: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dbsak4dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. That one allows the specification of a target width and height for the image so that you can scale it that way. That's a little more "direct" than doing it through matrix transformations, and possibly reduces the amount of floating-point math that might trip up the interpolation. That said, the results you are posting...

Comment: ... don't look remotely like a simple pixel offset/FP issue but the result of using something other than nearest neighbor sampling (bilinear or bicubic). Nearest neighbor should never give you pixel values that aren't there in the source image. Just like a sanity check but you might want to make sure you are actually using the correct input image, e.g.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to display 16-bit images with C#. I came across the same trouble that the colors in the totally same pixel is not the same. Finally I solved this trouble with the sample code below:

```
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor; 
            e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighSpeed;
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.None;

            e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Black); //Clear the background with the black color

            if(m_bmp != null)  //if m_bmp == null, then do nothing.
            {
                //To calculate the proper display area's width and height that fit the window.
                if (this.Width / (double)this.Height > m_bmp.Width / (double)m_bmp.Height)
                {
                    m_draw_height = (int)(this.Height * m_roomRatio);
                    m_draw_width = (int)(m_bmp.Width / (double)m_bmp.Height * m_draw_height);
                }
                else
                {
                    m_draw_width = (int)(this.Width * m_roomRatio);
                    m_draw_height = (int)(m_bmp.Height / (double)m_bmp.Width * m_draw_width);
                }

                //To calculate the starting point.
                m_draw_x = (int)((this.Width - m_draw_width) / 2.0 + m_offsetX / 2.0);
                m_draw_y = (int)((this.Height - m_draw_height) / 2.0 + m_offsetY / 2.0);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(m_bmp, m_draw_x, m_draw_y, m_draw_width, m_draw_height);

                //draw some useful information
                string window_info = "m_draw_x" + m_draw_x.ToString() + "m_draw_width" + m_draw_width.ToString();
                e.Graphics.DrawString(window_info, this.Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow), 0, 20);
            }
```

BTW, why don't you try to use double buffer to increase the performance of drawing images?

Here is the effect:

[image]

Hope that will help.